# Why doesn't TinyTex include biber?

Tags: biblatex, biber, tinytex

[TinyTeX](https://yihui.org/tinytex/) is very useful for installing LaTeX for continuous integration environments. I am surprised to see that [biber](http://biblatex-biber.sourceforge.net/) is not part of the distribution. Is there a reason for this, or am I missing something?

As it stands the best solution to get biber set up on continuous integration is to include binaries in my repositories, which is far from ideal.

Comment: well it's tiny... for the latex-project CI we start from texlive `selected_scheme scheme-infraonly` which I think is even smaller than tinytex, and then add what we need with `tlmgr install...`

Comment: I'm not sure there's an objective answer here: the question of 'what is essential' depends so much on the use case of the person creating the list of packages.

Comment: @David Carlisle that's fair. biber is ~40MB, which is probably about the size of the rest of the existing combined distribution. In contrast bibtex is 250KB.

Comment: (Does TinyTeX include the `bibtex` executable? In MacTeX2021, the `bibtex` executable occupies 544848 bytes, whereas the `biber` executable occupies a whopping 40258688 bytes of space. That's a ratio of roughly 1 to 74!) I suppose that if one of the objectives of TinyTeX is to keep the distribution, well, *tiny*, omitting a 40-MByte program and its multitude of auxiliary files must be a no-brainer.

Comment: so you can probably add biber (and cache in your CI) via tlmgr and not put biber in your source repository)